# What is the `current` correct format for Python Docstrings according to PEP standards?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

I've been looking all over the web for the current standards for Python Docstrings and I've come across different answers for different scenarios. What is the currently most-accepted and wide-spread docstring format that I should use?
These are the ones that I've found so far:

Sphinx format (1): `:param type name: description`

Sphinx format (2):
`:py:param type name: description`

NumPy format: `Parameters: __________  param: description`

Other formats:

`Args: param (type): description`

`Parameters: param (type): description`

I just want to document my code in a `standard` way that is accepted by almost every IDE (including VS Code and PyCharm) that also conforms to PEP and readthedocs, so I can also enable hover-over with mouse over the code to see description of the arguments.

I'm looking for current standards that are at least backwards compatible with Python 3.6 a since that's the base of the projects I work on.

Comment: Many tools will happily accept Sphinx and likely other styles, as well. Use the one you find easiest to work with and that your tool(s) support. PEP-257 is almost 22 years old.

Comment: @Birb `22` years old... That's a really long time ago. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most widely accepted and standardized format for Python docstrings is the one defined in the PEP 257 - Docstring Conventions. This format is supported by most IDEs, including VS Code and PyCharm, and is also used by the Sphinx and NumPy documentation tools.

The PEP 257 format for documenting function parameters is as follows:

```
def function_name(param1: type, param2: type) -> return_type:
    """
    Description of the function and its arguments.

    Parameters:
    param1 (type): Description of the first parameter.
    param2 (type): Description of the second parameter.

    Returns:
    return_type: Description of the return value.
    """
```

This format is compatible with Python 3.6 and later versions, and is also backward compatible with older versions of Python. It is recommended to follow this format for documenting function arguments in your code to ensure consistency and compatibility with different tools and IDEs.

Comment: How do you set this to be the default docstring in pycharm?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. PEP 257 nowhere specifies how parameters and return values shall be documented. As of today, there's no official stance on how to format parameters and return values. AFAIK the most commonly used formats are the Google and NumPy formats.